# Grouping and Sorting a Collection with Java 8 Streams (clean solution)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for better algorithm using streams to print sort professions according to salary.

The java class is:

```
public class Rh {

private int id;
private String nome;
private Double salario;
private String profissao;
private String cidade;
private String uf;
private String serie;
private Double peso;
private String sexo;
/* constructor and getters and setters */

}
```

Here is the code in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE rh
  (
  id serial primary key,
  nome character varying,
  salario numeric(9,2),
  profissao character varying,
  cidade character varying,
  uf character varying,
  serie_favorita character varying,
  peso numeric(6,2),
  sexo character varying
);

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Ana', '3000',     'Programador',                  'GOT',        '80',   'F');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Beatriz', '2000', 'Vendedor', 'Cianorte', 'PR',   'GOT',        '65.3', 'F');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Carla', '3200',   'Vendedor', 'Mambore', 'PR',    'Smallville', '67.1', 'F');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Carlos', '1800',  'Programador', 'Floripa', 'SC', 'BB',         '82.3', 'M');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Beto', '2200',    'Barista', 'Floripa', 'SC',     'BB',         '70.15','M');
INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Diogo', '2400',   'Professor', 'CM', 'PR',        'GOT',        '93',   'M');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Diego', '2500',   'Biologo', 'CM', 'PR',          'GOT',       '75',   'M');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Diego', '1500',   'Fisioterapeuta', 'Mambore', 'PR',    'GOT',         '70',   'M');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Bruno', '1550',   'Médico', 'Cascavel', 'PR',     'GOT',       '88',   'M');

INSERT INTO rh(nome, salario, profissao, cidade, uf, serie_favorita, peso, sexo) VALUES
            ('Fabio', '1455',   'Matemático', 'Floripa', 'SC',  'BB',        '96',   'M');
```

The desired query is:

```
SELECT profissao, avg(salario) FROM rh GROUP BY profissao ORDER BY avg(salario);
```

In java:

```
List<Rh> listaRh =  Arrays.asList(
    new Rh(1, "Ana", 3000.0, "Programador", null, null, "GOT", 80.0, "F"),
    new Rh(2, "Beatriz", 2000.0, "Vendedor", "Cianorte", "PR", "GOT", 65.3, "F"),
    new Rh(3, "Carla", 3200.0, "Vendedor", "Mambore", "PR", "SmallVille", 67.1, "F"),
    new Rh(4, "Carlos", 1800.0, "Programador", "Floripa", "SC", "BreakingBad", 82.3, "M"),
    new Rh(5, "Beto", 2200.0, "Barista", "Floripa", "SC", "BreakingBad", 70.15, "M"),
    new Rh(6, "Diogo", 2400.0, "Professor", "Campo Mourão", "PR", "GOT", 93.0, "M"),
    new Rh(7, "Diego", 2500.0, "Biólogo", "Campo Mourão", "PR", "GOT", 75.0, "M"),
    new Rh(8, "Diego", 1500.0, "Fisioterapeuta", "Mambore", "PR", "GOT", 70.0, "M"),
    new Rh(9, "Bruno", 1550.0, "Médico", "Cascavel", "PR", "GOT", 88.0, "M"),
    new Rh(10, "Fabio", 1455.0, "Matemático", "Floripa", "SC", "BreakingBad", 96.0, "M")
);
```

I got the following solution using streams:

```
Map<String, Double> result2 = listaRh.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        l -> l.getProfissao(),
        Collectors.averagingDouble(l -> l.getSalario())));

Map<String, Double> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

result2.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Double>comparingByValue())
    .forEachOrdered(e -> finalMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : finalMap.entrySet()) 
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"  "+entry.getValue());
```

My question is... Is there a "clean" solution to do the same thing using streams?

Comment: There is no need to create that `finalMap` at all, `result2.entrySet().stream() .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println( e.getKey()+"  "+e.getValue());`

Comment: I thought you could collect directly to a TreeMap, but actually the constructor only takes a key Comparator not an entry Comparator.

Comment: Sorting result sets is something that a database does well.  don't try to drive a nail with nail clippers.

Comment: Define "clean."

Comment: Why? Why do people insist on streams?

Comment: @JoeC Because they find that streams make code more concise and readable, once you get used to reading them. Methods like "groupingBy", "averagingDouble", "forEach" and so on immediatly give you an outline of what steps are taken, thereby replacing those typical inline comments often used to explain the classic code alternative for the same step. Creating a map is a typical example where streams can reduce boilerplate code, focusing on **what** goes into the map instead of **how** it is put into the map.

Comment: Thank you all... You say everything @MalteHartwig... I'm preparing for an exam and SQL is not an alternative....

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just do it in SQL, like I assume you did before?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution using just streams might include:

- Method references: e.g. `Rh::getProfissao` instead of `l -> l.getProfissao()`
- Using a `Collector` instead of manually building the result map
- Static imports

Using the above ideas with your example:

```
import static java.util.Map.Entry.comparingByValue;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.averagingDouble;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```

...

```
Map<String, Double> result2 = listaRh.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Rh::getProfissao, averagingDouble(Rh::getSalario)));

Map<String, Double> finalMap = result2.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparingByValue())
    .collect(toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));

for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : finalMap.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue());
```

If you don't need `finalMap` besides for printing its content, you can avoid using the LinkedHashMap and toMap collector entirely:

```
result2.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparingByValue())
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution by [SteamEx forked](https://github.com/landawn/streamex) by me

```
StreamEx.of(rhList)
    .groupByToEntry(Rh::getProfissao, Fn.averagingDouble(Rh::getSalario))
    .sortedByValue(Fn.naturalOrder()).toMap(LinkedHashMap::new);
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing us to this library, I'm going to look at it carefully.